# RegExp для всех языков, но без спец символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение:

`const reg = /(?:\s|^)[A-Za-z0-9\-\.\_]+(?:\s|$)/`

Принимает только английский алфавит, и запрещает спец символы

Как расширить, чтобы принимал не только английский алфавит, но и буквы всех других мировых языков?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы найти любую букву, необходимо использовать `\p{Alphabetic}` или `\p{L}` (первый конструкт находит чуть больше символов, чем второй). В JavaScript также требуется добавить флаг `u`:

```js
const reg = /(?:\s|^)[\p{Alphabetic}0-9\-._]+(?:\s|$)/u
const reg = /(?:\s|^)[\p{L}0-9\-._]+(?:\s|$)/u
```

Если нужно заодно находить диакритические знаки, доюавьте `\p{M}` (или `\p{Mn}`):

```js
const reg = /(?:\s|^)[\p{Alphabetic}\p{M}0-9\-._]+(?:\s|$)/u
const reg = /(?:\s|^)[\p{L}\p{M}0-9\-._]+(?:\s|$)/u
```

Если пробельные символы должны быть исключены из совпадения, используйте `(?<!\S)` и `(?!\S)` вместо незахватывающих групп:

```js
const reg = /(?<!\S)[\p{Alphabetic}\p{M}0-9\-._]+(?!\S)/u
const reg = /(?<!\S)[\p{L}\p{M}0-9\-._]+(?!\S)/u
```

Если нужно найти все вхождения, добавьте `g` после или перед `u`.

Да, в символьных классах нет нужды экранировать символы `.` и `_`. Собственно, если поставить дефис в конце или начале символьного класса, его тоже не надо экранировать, но многие совершают ошибку при добавлении других символов в символьный класс, забывая о том, что нельзя в таких случаях перемещать дефис, поэтому лучше оставить его как есть, то есть экранированным в середине класса.